# "message": "Validation error of type MissingFieldArgument: Missing field argument DeviceID @ 'listApneAppsyncSubTests'" requesting wrong model

Tags: flutter, dart, aws-amplify, flutter-streambuilder, flutter-aws-amplify

i am using amplify to subscribe the event and the subscription established but error in fetching real time data i am trying to get data from onCreateApneAppsyncSubTest but its requesting the model listApneAppsyncSubTests and giving the validation error which never mensioned.

[image: Errors]

the error indicates the missing feild but i not mensioned that in schema

I tried to subscribe the event and fetch the realtimeData
[image: Here is my scheama]

remaining code
[image]
[image]
Can anyone tell me whats am doing wrong with the code or with the schema